# The difference total neutrino energy and neutrino enery for oscillation in Supnernova(SN)

Tags: energy, neutrinos, supernova

I have very naive question about neutrino energy.
I show in some papers the total neutrino energy in SN is same as 99% gravitational binding energy. So for 1987A SN is almost $10^{53}$erg. But when we consider neutrino oscillation (like here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation) we take just 10MeV or 50MeV for neutrino energy.
I wonder how is this neutrino energy decided and what is the difference between total neutrino energy? (is it average neutrino energy like $3kT=\langle E_{\nu}\rangle$?) 
I am waiting for someone to help me.

Comment: "Total" as in "if you add of the energy of all the individual neutrinos"...